# InfoPath 2010 submit error

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I am facing an issue when submitting an InfoPath form to  a SharePoint forms library, I have 2 WFE servers with NLB, using **HTTP** for intranet(for local users) and the web application is available through the internet using **HTTPS**
when submitting the form the local server using HTTP its working fine, but when accessing SharePoint externally through https I'm getting the below-warning message and I can't submit the form since I have **"Try Again"** and **"Exit Form"**

**Warning**

> The form cannot be submitted to the Web server either because
>   your computer is offline or because the host server is currently
>   unavailable. If this problem persists, contact your network
>   administrator.

Comment: Maybe this article [problem submitting InfoPath forms](http://bytelab.blogspot.com/2008/03/problem-submitting-infopath-forms-using.html) could help.

Comment: I will work on this and will keep you updated. 
Thanks

Comment: As discussed with the network team, they told me that there is no ISA server and they are using a 3rd party hardware NLB and it has a rule to redirect all HTTP external requests to HTTPS. and SSL certificate is installed on this Hardware not on SharePoint servers. we are checking with the 3rd party vendor and they will provide us with the solution, i will keep you updated.

Answer (score 0):

**For my case with 2 WFE servers , the Resolution was as the below:**

> 1- configure AAM and insure that (http://) is mapped to
>   (https://).
>
> 2- Installed a self-signed certificate on WFE1 IIS.
>
> 3- Export the Self-Signed certificate from IIS and add it to
>   SharePoint Trust relationships
>   (http:///_admin/ManageTrust.aspx)
>
> 5- restart IIS.
>
> 6- Import the same certificate to WFE2's IIS and restart IIS for WFE2.

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually occurs if the current page has been hosted within a secure HTTPS environment. Meanwhile, it embeds unsecured HTTP contents/scripts

For SharePoint 2013 / 2010 you can also check this details article.

[The form cannot be submitted to the web server either because your computer is offline or because the host server is currently unavailable. If this problem persists, contact your network administrator](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/04/30/the-form-cannot-be-submitted-to-the-web-server-either-because-your-computer-is-offline-or-because-the-host-server-is-currently-unavailable-if-this-problem-persists-contact-your-network-administrator/)